# Prevent R script from finishing when scheduling fixed delay executor

Tags: java, r, graalvm, fastr

I plan to write an R script using FastR implementation which looks like

```r
    java.addToClasspath("build/libs/polyglot-example-f.jar")
    clientClass <- java.type('org.algo.polyglot.JavaClient')
    javaClient <- new(clientClass, threadPoolSize=10)
    javaClient$startScheduleWithFixedDelay(5)
```

The `org.algo.polyglot.JavaClient` class looks like (packaged into a jar):

```java
    package org.algo.polyglot;

    import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;
    import org.graalvm.polyglot.HostAccess;

    import java.text.MessageFormat;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.graalvm.polyglot.HostAccess.Export;

    public class JavaClient {

        private final ScheduledExecutorService service;

        @Export
        public JavaClient(int threadPoolSize) {
            this.service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        }

        @Export
        public void startScheduleWithFixedDelay(int delayInSeconds) {
            service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                    () -> {
                        postMessage(fetchMessage());
                    },
                    0,
                    delayInSeconds,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS
            );
        }

        @Export
        public void startScheduleWithFixedRate(int period) {
            service.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                    () -> {},
                    0,
                    period,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS
            );
        }

        @Export
        public PolyglotMessage fetchMessage() {
            return new PolyglotMessage(
                    RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10, 15),
                    RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10, 15),
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
            );
        }

        @Export
        public void postMessage(PolyglotMessage message) {
            System.out.println("[Printed from JavaClient] Posting message: " + message.toString());
        }
    }
```

When running the script with `Rscript sample.R --polyglot` the script finished execution with output:

```
    $ Rscript sample.R --polyglot
    NULL
```

I have these motives:

- R script should be the entry point, because my use case requires me to leverage java functionality in R
- Run the R script with the provided jar
- Execute the script with Rscript
- <s>Get a `ScheduledExecutorService` running with either fixed delay or fixed rate from the R script itself without the R script finishing execution (Stay alive till the service is running)</s> This can be fixed by returning the scheduled future and awaiting on it using `ScheduledFuture$get()` The changes made to the script and code are:

```r
    future <- javaClient$startScheduleWithFixedDelay(5)
    future$get()
```

```java
    @Export
    public ScheduledFuture<?> startScheduleWithFixedDelay(int delayInSeconds) {
        return service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                () -> {
                    postMessage(fetchMessage());
                },
                0,
                delayInSeconds,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
        );
    }
```

- Pass a function to the executor from the R script so that the function is called accordingly by the ScheduledExecutorService (an R function can be passed to run in java code and the receiver will be a functional interface, example:)

```r
    myFunc <- function() {
        # do some stuff
    }

javaClient$runProvidedFunction(myFunc)
```

```java
    @Export
    public void runProvidedFunction(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
```

But the access from different threads is restricted

- Build a native image with the runnable script and jar

I want to know if these motives are possible and if possible, the proper way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Run the R script with the provided jar

It seems that you figured it out yourself. Either you can use `java.addToClasspath` or you should be able to add to the class path when starting R/Rscript by `--vm.cp=...`. Both options work only in the JVM mode.

> Execute the script with Rscript

Again, seems you figured it out?

> Pass a function to the executor from the R script so that the function is called accordingly by the ScheduledExecutorService

This is tricky. R is single threaded language and so is FastR. You cannot execute R code from multiple threads, but what you can do is to create multiple FastR contexts and use a new context in each thread (you can use ThreadLocal for that). See https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/embed-languages. You should be able to use the Context API from the Java code that you call from R and create new contexts.

> Build a native image with the runnable script and jar

That should be fine. Note that there are some known issues with some R packages and native image that we have not fixed yet.

The entry point must be some Java application that uses the Context API to start FastR. The R script you can embed into the Java application as a String or a resource. Note that the R code will not be ahead-of-time compiled. It will still be JIT compiled at runtime, but everything else will be ahead-of-time compiled: your Java code, any Java libs you use, FastR interpreter and runtime.

Comment: I should have added that I wanted the R script to be the entry point and I really wanted to leverage multithreading, scheduled executors from java in R to make the R code somewhat reactive. Is there a way to force multithreaded behavior? I was already able to pass a function from R and receive it as a functional interface in the java code.

Comment: There is no semantics for multi-threading in R as the language. We could make something up for FastR, but updating FastR to support it would be a large effort.

Comment: You can still make the R script be the entry point by writing small Java wrapper that does nothing but just creating Context and executing the R script.

Comment: Btw. FastR can be executed from multiple threads, it just must be one thread at a time, i.e., not concurrently, if that can help anyhow.